# Wix conditionally deploy fragment

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I want to deploy the files conditionally depending on which IIS is installed.
Every time i deploy it, both feature are deployed.
please help...
Following is part of the code fragment...

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Patch Management" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Start tech" UpgradeCode="739a025e-0758-4926-9528-2ad9a026e77a" Codepage="1252">
    <Package Id="*" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Manufacturer="Star tech" Description="Server" Comments="(c)2016 Star tech" InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes"></Package>
    <Property Id="IIS_MAJORVERSION">
        <RegistrySearch Id="RS_IIS_MAJORVERSION_2" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" Name="MajorVersion" Type="raw">
        </RegistrySearch>
    </Property>
    <Feature Id="ServerFeature" Title="Server Feature" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="EXETXT_CMPGRP" />

        <Feature Id="ServerSite" Title="Server Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="IISWEB_CMPGRP"/>
            <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[IIS_MAJORVERSION="#5"]]]></Condition>
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="ServerSiteIIS5" Title="Server Feature IIS5 " Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="IISWEB_CMPGRP_5"/>
            <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[IIS_MAJORVERSION<>"#5"]]]></Condition>
        </Feature>
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is happening because you embedded your features under a parent feature.

The [InstallDefault](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html) attribute of the feature element has 3 values. I think the default value is followParent so these features are forced to install regardless of the conditional within them. I think you can fix this by settings the InstallDefault to source or local (untested by me, you'd have to test this leave a comment if one works!) or don't nest the features within each other. Unless you are showing a feature tree in the install UI it doesn't make a difference to the user whether or not all your features are together or not. You could also group your features together into a logical unit using the <FeatureGroup> element.